# Function that sends email when user doesnt input data being too slow, flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello everyone I made a function that sends an email whenever a user doesn't input data for 14 days unfortunately when executed it works but it is very slow. I would love some tips on how to make it faster. And better written

Function

```
def enviar_email_checkup():
users= [1,2]
for user in users:
    ultimadata=db.session.query(Dado.DataDeInsercao).filter_by(user_id = user).order_by(Dado.DataDeInsercao.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
    dueduser=db.session.query(UsuarioDB.EmailDB,UsuarioDB.id).filter_by(id = user).order_by(UsuarioDB.id.desc()).limit(1).scalar()
    datahoje=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    diff= datahoje-ultimadata
    if diff.days >= 14:
        msg = Message('Falta de dados',sender='ivgnoreply@gmail.com', recipients= [dueduser])
        msg.body =   'Isso e um email para vc parar de ser vagabundo'
        mail.send(msg)
    else:
        break
```

Route when executed

```
@Principal.route("/HomePage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def HomePage():
     enviar_email_checkup()
     return render_template("HomePage.html",title = "HomePage")
```

Comment: How about reading all the rows at once and processing them in-memory? If the data is too large to read in a single go, you can consider chunking. The bottle neck here must be the database access and you should try to avoid that. I suggest using pandas to read multiple rows at once and applying the check condition using the apply method which I found is usually fast than looping. Pandas allows you to use vectorized code to speed things up.

Comment: The best way is to move this task from http request handler into some background process. Simple cron-job, or celery worker, whatever. And use single request to db as others already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making database queries in a loop is very inefficient.  It's usually better to construct a single query that fetches all the required data at once.

It seems that what you want to do is to identify all users who do not have an entry on the `Dado` table after a certain date.  We can do this by creating a query with a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```py
# This example uses pure-sqlalchemy, but converting to flask-sqlalchemy should not be 
# too difficult, for example 
# session.query(UsuarioDB).filter(...) -> UsuarioDB.query.filter(...)

from sqlalchemy.sql import exists

diff_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(14)

stmt = exists().where(sa.and_(
                          Dado.DataDeInsercao >= diff_date,
                          UsuarioDB.id == Dado.user_id))

# The '~' here is a negation operator
q = session.query(UsuarioDB).filter(~stmt)

for usuario in q:
    # send message
```

The query generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT usuario.id AS usuario_id, usuario."EmailDB" AS "usuario_EmailDB" 
FROM usuario 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM dado 
WHERE dado."DataDeInsercao" >= ? AND usuario.id = dado.user_id))
```

If you have created a relationship between your models, say like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import orm

class UsuarioDB(Base):
    ...
    dados = orm.relationship('Dado')
```

then we can simplify the Python code a little (the same SQL is generated):

```py
q = session.query(UsuarioDB).filter(~UsuarioDB.dados.any(Dado.DataDeInsercao >= diff_date))

for usuario in q:
    # send message
```

Sending emails in loops can also be time-consuming if a new connection to the server is being created in each iteration.  It may be worth checking if there is a bulk sending option.

Comment: Loved your tips, specially the bulk email, and the idea to only query the users who didnt insert any data for a while seens way more promissing  than simpling filtering through all of then thank you so much for the help appreciate it.